# What to put in the throws clause of an interface method?

Tags: java, oop, exception

Suppose I have interface `I` and two classes `A` and `B` that implement it.
The implementation of method `f` of this interface in `A` throws one set of exceptions and the implementation in `B` throws another set. The only common ancestor of these exceptions is `java.lang.Exception`. Is it reasonable to declare `f` throwing `java.lang.Exception` in this case? Any other alternatives?

The reason why I am asking is that on the one hand `java.lang.Exception` seems too general to me and one the other hand listing all exceptions seems impractical considering possible other implementations.

Example:

```
interface I {
    void f() throws Exception;
}

class A implements I {
    public void f() throws IOException {}
}

class B implements I {
    public void f() throws InterruptedException {}
}
```

Comment: You've discovered the biggest reason why checked exceptions are generally considered a failed experiment in language design...

Comment: @Michael Borgwardt - your comments and downvotes are off topic.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The reason for using an interface is to abstract away the implementation details.

By throwing these exceptions, you're exposing implementation details that probably should be abstracted away.

Perhaps it would be best to define a new exception.  Then each implementation of f() would catch the exceptions it knows about and throw the new exception instead so you'd have:

```
interface I {
    void f() throws MyException;
}

class A implements I {
    public void f() throws MyException {
         try {
             ...
         } catch (IOException e) {
             throw new MyException(e);
         }
    }
}

class B implements I {
    public void f() throws MyException {
         try {
             ...
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
             throw new MyException(e);
         }
    }
}
```

By wrapping the implementation exception, you're still exposing it to the caller and that can bite you when you're calling remote methods.  In those cases you need to do more work to return useful information in a generic way.

**Edit**
There seems to be a bit of a dispute going on about the correct approach.

When we call f(), we'll need code like:

```
I instanceOfI = getI();
try {
    instanceOfI.f();
}
catch ( /* What should go here ? */ )
```

It comes down to what is a good Exception class to put in the catch block.
With OP's original code we could catch `Exception` and then maybe try to see which subclass we have, or not depending on requirements.  Or we could individually catch each subclass but then we'd have to add catch blocks when new implementations throw different exceptions.

If we used Runtime exceptions it would come to much the same thing except that we could alternatively defer the exception handling to a caller method without even giving the possibility of exceptions any thought.

If we used my suggestion of using a new, wrapped exception then this means we have to catch `MyException` and then try to see what additional information is available.  This essentially becomes very like just using an Exception, but requires extra work for the limited benefit of having a `bespoke` exception that can be tailored to the purpose.

Comment: +1 I think that's the way to go. In java you just have to create a new class for anything.

Comment: +1 although I wouldn't suggest an interface throw a plain `Exception`

Comment: Off-topic point: "abstract away the implementation details" from whom? the user of `class A` or `class B`? If i take one scenario of an `interface`, any user who wants to use `interface FilenameFilter` has to implement his own class before using it. No body else would have the implementation before hand to use this interface. I would say "interface is an aggregation of peripheral(not-core) functionality of concrete sub classes with given contracts".

Answer (score 3):

This seems a bit backward.  You should be throwing exceptions that are relevant and possibly specific to your interface, or not at all.  Change the implementations to wrap a common Exception class (although not `Exception` itself).  If you can't deal with this you may want to wrap the Exceptions in the implementations with a RuntimeException.

Comment: @Michael: I think that hinting at the checked/unchecked exception debate is completely unrelated to the issues raised by the question.

Comment: @Michael Borgwardt - Throwing RuntimeException in this case is a very bad idea IMO.  It is just a way of getting around declaring the exceptions that your interface throws.  If you don't like checked exceptions, switch to C#.

Comment: @Adrian: No, this issue is at the heart of that debate.

Comment: @Stephen: Getting around declaring the exceptions is exactly the point. Because it's not the interface that throws the exceptions, it's the implementations (which may not even have existed when the interface was written, and whose implementors may not be able to change the interface code). Having the interface define its own app-specific exception as Adrian suggests is one alternative, but IMO a lot of trouble for little gain. And language use can evolve around bad features.

Comment: @Michael: Let's pretend that the methods were defined to *return* the exceptions rather than to *throw* them.  How would that alter our design decision?  Should it alter our design decision?  Is it even valid to make that comparison?

Comment: @Adrian: well, you can only have a single return type, but apart from that you're basically describing error codes. And one of the two generally accepted major advantages of exceptions over error codes is that they can be dealt with higher in the call stack without each method in the stack having to be aware of them and passing them on explicitly. With checked exceptions, you pretty much lose that advantage.

Comment: @Michael - I seriously hope that the Java language does NOT evolve away from checked exceptions.  Indeed, I don't think it would be technically possible.

Comment: @Stephen: there's a reason why no other language has adopted the "feature". As for technical possibilities, it would not be hard at all to make compiler enforcement of checked exceptions optional, though I wouldn't consider that a good idea either. We'll have to live with them where they occur so far, but language *use* is definitely evolving away from checked exceptions and towards unchecked ones.

Answer (score 1):

You could just declare the exceptions you throw

```
void f() throws IOException, InterruptedException;
```

If you use a decent IDE, it will correct this for you.  I just throw the exception in the method, which the IDE gives the optionsto add to the method clause and its interface.

Comment: What if I add in the future one more implementation that throws something else?